# Bash - Unexpected End of File

Tags: bash

I've been working on a bash script to run tests on a program and I can't seem to be able to find the syntax error. When I use -x, it tells me it is expecting a } but I can't find it.

Please see the code underneath.

```
#!/bin/bash
usagearg() {
    echo "You're missing an argument on the command line!" >&2}
usagemiss() {
    echo "A file requested in your filestem is missing or cannot be read!" >&2}
if [ ${#} -ne 2 ]; then
    usagearg;
    exit 1;
fi
x=1
endp=`wc -l ${1}`
end=$((endp+1))
while [ ${x} -ne ${end} ] ; do
    # redacted code which isn't related to the issue at hand.
done
```

I feel like I've closed all the loops and ifs, and all the brackets, so I don't understand why I'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: You may need to close the function `usagemiss()`

Comment: Try moving the closing braces to a new line in the usagearg() and usagemiss() functions.  They may be getting swallowed by the redirection.  Also looks better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The list of commands inside the braces for the compound command must be terminated by either a semicolon or a newline; the closing brace itself is not sufficient.

Either use

```
usagearg() {
    echo "You're missing an argument on the command line!" >&2; }
```

or

```
usagearg() {
    echo "You're missing an argument on the command line!" >&2
}
```

As written, your code treats the right brace as simply another character, and part of the output redirection since there is no intervening whitespace.

---

As to why this is necessary, you have to go back to how `bash` defines certain characters. There is the set of *metacharacters*, which can separate words when unquoted. There is also the set of *control operators*, which are vaguely defined as performing a "control function". The right brace `}` is in neither category. (Why? I'm not sure, but I think it's related to the use of braces in parameter expansion (`${foo}`) which preclude it having otherwise special handling.)